# PHP Fatal error When compiling Magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media' not found in /home/public_html/app/code/LitExtension/Core/Model/Preference/Product/Media.php on line 7
```

Full Code

```
<?php

namespace LitExtension\Core\Model\Preference\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Media extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media
{
    public function addImage(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $file,
        $mediaAttribute = null,
        $move = false,
        $exclude = true,
        $label = ''
    ) {
        $file = $this->mediaDirectory->getRelativePath($file);
        if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isFile($file)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The image does not exist.'));
        }

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
        $imgExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
        if (!isset($pathinfo['extension']) || !in_array(strtolower($pathinfo['extension']), $imgExtensions)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Please correct the image file type.'));
        }

        $fileName = \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::getCorrectFileName($pathinfo['basename']);
        $dispretionPath = \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::getDispretionPath($fileName);
        $fileName = $dispretionPath . '/' . $fileName;

        $fileName = $this->getNotDuplicatedFilename($fileName, $dispretionPath);

        $destinationFile = $this->mediaConfig->getTmpMediaPath($fileName);

        try {
            /** @var $storageHelper \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database */
            $storageHelper = $this->fileStorageDb;
            if ($move) {
                $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile($file, $destinationFile);

                //If this is used, filesystem should be configured properly
                $storageHelper->saveFile($this->mediaConfig->getTmpMediaShortUrl($fileName));
            } else {
                $this->mediaDirectory->copyFile($file, $destinationFile);

                $storageHelper->saveFile($this->mediaConfig->getTmpMediaShortUrl($fileName));
                $this->mediaDirectory->changePermissions($destinationFile, DriverInterface::WRITEABLE_FILE_MODE);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('We couldn\'t move this file: %1.', $e->getMessage()));
        }

        $fileName = str_replace('\\', '/', $fileName);

        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData($attrCode);
        $position = 0;
        if (!is_array($mediaGalleryData)) {
            $mediaGalleryData = ['images' => []];
        }

        foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as &$image) {
            if (isset($image['position']) && $image['position'] > $position) {
                $position = $image['position'];
            }
        }

        $position++;
        $mediaGalleryData['images'][] = [
            'file' => $fileName,
            'position' => $position,
            'label' => $label,
            'disabled' => (int)$exclude,
        ];

        $product->setData($attrCode, $mediaGalleryData);

        if ($mediaAttribute !== null) {
            $this->setMediaAttribute($product, $mediaAttribute, $fileName);
        }

        return $fileName;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seem your custom extension causes this issue. Add more code lines of your custom extension.

Comment: Just added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

The class does not seem to exist anymore in the code base

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend

Did you write the extension ? If yes, with which Magento Version? Then compare the changes from that version to the current one.

Otherwise contact the dev of the extension.

Comment: I didnt write the code, It was for Magento 2.04

Comment: So ask the extension's Developer for an update